# How to convert your script into a class?

Tags: python, list, variables

I wrote a code to convert some text in pdf file into a pandas dataframe. Code works very well normally, but when I try to fit it into class and define function for it, it returns with error.

```
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
import re

cols = ["Declaration Number", "Declaration Date", "Warehouse", "Quantity", "Number of boxes", "Product name", "Invoice Number"]
dataset = []
quant = []
date = []
decl_date = []

decl = re.compile(r'\d{8}AN\d{6}')
decd = re.compile(r'\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}')
whse = re.compile(r'ANTREPO | LİMAN')
qty = re.compile(r'\d.KAP')
prod = re.compile(r'Ticari')
invNo = re.compile(r'Fatura')

class pdf():
    def __init__(self):
        self.kap = None
        self.kg = None


    def FirstPage():
        
        with pdfplumber.open("44550500AN087999.pdf") as pdf:
            page = pdf.pages[0]
            text = page.extract_text()

        for line in text.split('\n'):

            if decl.search(line):
                decl_num = line.split()[-1]

            if decd.search(line):
                decl_date = []
                date = []
                decl_date.append(line.split())
                date = decl_date[1][-1]
            if whse.search(line):
                warehouse = line.split()
                
            if qty.search(line):
                quant = line.split()
            
            
        
        kap = quant[0] + " " + quant[1]
        kg = quant[2] + " " + quant[3]
```

when I run it it returns with several errors:

For instance:

```
<ipython-input-26-bc082b4afef0> in FirstPage()
     20                 date = []
     21                 decl_date.append(line.split())
---> 22                 date = decl_date[1][-1]
     23             if whse.search(line):
     24                 warehouse = line.split()

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I am probably defining the variables wrong but I am a newby so, anyone have any idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are only putting one element into `decl_date`, and then trying to access the second element inside that list, which does not exist.

Your use of `line.split()` seems incorrect to me. The way you have used them essentially only puts the string into a 1-element list `"string" -> ["string"]`.

I assume you want to split the string by using the regex in each if-statement, in that case change `line.split()` to `pattern.split(line)[index]`, swapping out pattern and index